# Can you turn an insulator into a conductor without dielectric breakdown?

Tags: conductors, dielectric

The question is quite simple: Can you turn an insulator into a conductor without "brute-forcing" it by increasing the voltage? I know that at low temperatures, some dielectrics become superconductors, and I want to know if other ways exist. Perhaps even practically applicable ones.

Comment: Does [this] (https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/190448/can-you-dope-insulators) help?